# Micro SD Card causing Problem in Tablet

Tags: settings, external-sd, sd-card

**Device: Pipo N7 MT8163
Android 7.0**

I am using a Micro SD Card (128GB) in my tablet. As far as I know the device is supposed to be able to handle this card. The tablet recognizes it without a problem. What I am experiencing is, that I find different areas of the tablet malfunctioning. for example I can't download or install new apps while the card is mounted in the tablet. If I unmount/eject it then I'm fine.

I also find that most of the time I can't delete data or cache in the Settings -> Apps. Even when I can delete it doesn't update the data and chache amounts.

Usually when you go to the apps in settings it shows under each app the amount of space the app is taking. When my card is mounted I don't get this info.
These are only a couple of the problems I seem to have. As soon as I eject the card all goes back to normal.

I have tried to google this problem but wasn't able to find anything related to my problem.

Please if someone can advise on what I can do

Comment: I had a similar problem. I couldn't get to the root cause but I copied the contents to PC, bought another SD card and copied from PC and it worked fine. Strangely, the original SD card worked fine on other devices and is in use till date.

Comment: This didn't help.with the second card I have the same problem.

Comment: In that case, I suspect a hardware issue but to make sure it is only hardware, I would suggest factory reset (after saving data). If it continues after factory reset, more likely hardware

Comment: When I do a factory reset it helps for a little while and then it goes back to giving me problems. This is the reason I'm thinking it may be that the device can't handle such a big card.

Comment: Big card could be one reason - you would need to check with a smaller card and also see the phone specs to see what's the maximum size supported.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question as far as I know it should support 128GB cards. Its a little bit hard to find decent info on these China devices.